# Boost.Asio functions under the hood

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I am just wondering how Boost.Asio functions like `async_read_until` works under the hood. Consider an example code:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/process.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

namespace ba = boost::asio;
namespace bp = boost::process;

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

int main()
{
  ba::io_context context(1);
  ba::steady_timer timer(context);
  bp::async_pipe pipe(context);
  ba::streambuf buffer;

  std::thread thread([&]()
  {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(3s);
    pipe.write_some(ba::buffer("END"));
  });
  thread.detach();

  ba::async_read_until(pipe, buffer, "END", [&](const auto& code, std::size_t size)
  {
    if (!code)
    {
      timer.cancel();
      std::cout << "Reading finished!" << std::endl;
    }
  });

  timer.expires_from_now(10s);
  timer.async_wait([&](const auto& code)
  {
    if (!code)
    {
      context.stop();
      std::cout << "Timer expired!" << std::endl;
    }
  });

  context.run();

  return 0;
}
```

I have tried to experiment with this sample code and invert durations for `sleep_for` and `async_wait` and this code worked as expected. But how is it possible? `io_context` uses only one thread. Shouldn't reading and waiting be queued? How `io_context` manages to perform two blocking operations in the same time in such circumstances?

Comment: You could always check the [source code](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/more/getting_started/).

Answer (score 0):

See [CppCon 2016: Michael Caisse "Asynchronous IO with Boost.Asio"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rwOv_tw2eA4&t=) for an excellent description of how `asio` works.

Answer (score 0):

Different platforms have different mechanisms to wait on multiple file descriptors/handles.

Windows uses overlapped IO and IO completion ports. Linux uses epoll, BSD uses Kqueues and some platforms use select. ASIO abstracts over these mechanisms and provides a consistent cross platform API.

Do get an idea how ASIO works, pick one of the above and try create your own implementation.